# Windows 7 not showing on Grub 2 list

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, linux-mint, grub2

I have Linux Mint and Windows 7 installed on two separate drives.  I have bounced between the two all day (initially trying to get mint to show in the windows boot list, and now working on getting windows to show in grub) - so I know that they both work fine.

As it stands Mint boots perfectly, displaying the grub menu first.  Just no option to boot into Windows. I have tried various approaches, including using `os-prober` and others as suggested on many other sites.

Can anybody give me a checklist of things I need to do or something along those lines?  Are there any common pitfalls that I might have hit when dual booting Windows and Linux on separate drives?